# d3js Force-Directed Paths on Center of Image or on the sides/bottom/top

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have a graph with arrows on the edges. It all works fine. However, the lines start at the top left which is not really that nice. So it would be nice to have them start at the middle of the images. Or is there a possibility to let them start at the sides or/bottom depending on the angle of the edges?
Initially I thought about adding a value in the tick function, but adding to d.source.x returns an Error.

```
link.selectAll("path").attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
    dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
    //dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    dr = 0;
    return "M" + 
    d.source.x +  
    "," + 
    d.source.y +
    "A" + 
    dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
    d.target.x +
    "," + 
    d.target.y;
});
```

I created a jsfiddle for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/riasc/zh677re5/54/)

Solution:
In the case of images with different sizes there is the function imagesize that determines the size of an image link:

```
// determine the size (width, height) of an image link
function imagesize(d) {
    var self = d3.select(this);
    function loaded() {
        d.width = img.width;
        d.height = img.height;
        self.attr('width', d.width);
        self.attr('height', d.height);
    }
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = self.attr('href');
    if(img.complete) {
        loaded();
    } else {
        img.addEventListener('load', loaded);
        img.addEventListener('error', function() {
            console.debug('error');
        });
    }
}
```

That function will be called on the nodes via `.each(imagesize)`, and then I can add half of the width/height to d.x.

```
link.selectAll("path").attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        //dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        dr = 0;
        return "M" + 
        (d.source.x + (d.source.width ? d.source.width/2 : 0)) +  
        "," + 
        (d.source.y + (d.source.height ? d.source.height/2 : 0)) +
        "A" + 
        dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
        (d.target.x + (d.target.width ? d.target.width/2 : 0)) +
        "," + 
        (d.target.y + (d.target.height ? d.target.height/2 : 0));
    });
```

However, is there still the possibility to add the sources and targets in a more subtle way? Like on the left/right or top/bottom site depending on the orientation of the paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the links you need to do it like this:

```
link.selectAll("path").attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            //dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            dr = 0;
            return "M" + 
            (d.source.x +30)+ //here 30 is width/2 of a node 
            "," + 
            (d.source.y +30)+ //here 30 is height/2 of a node
            "A" + 
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
            (d.target.x + 30)+ //here 30 is width/2 of target node
            "," + 
            (d.target.y + 30); //here 30 is height/2 of target node
        });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7hkwncha/)

You can change the number 30(shown above) to whatever number as per your choice of how you want to show the link.

Comment: ahh. I think I missed the brackets. Thanks.